# How to use regex to parse a S3 bucket list of files - Python

Tags: python, regex, amazon-s3

I have the following method:

```
def scan_s3dir(dirname):
    try:
        cmd = "s3cmd ls {s3bucket} --recursive".format(s3bucket=dirname)
        output = subprocess.check_output([cmd],
                                         stdin=None,
                                         shell=True)
        #s3://dgsecure/test_data/
        regex = "dgsecure/test_data/[^/]*/(\S+)*"
        installers = re.findall(regex, output)
        print installers
    except Exception, e:
        print e
        sys.exit(2)
```

when I execute `s3cmd ls /path/to/bucket --recursive` I get:

```
2014-02-14 02:21         0   s3://path/to/bucket/
2014-02-14 17:32       236   s3://path/to/bucket/foo.txt
2014-02-26 23:31      6035   s3://path/to/bucket/bar.txt
2014-02-14 22:17      2960   s3://path/to/bucket/baz.txt
```

from that regular expression, I want to produce a list all the files, including the `subdir` present in `//path/to/bucket/` for example like:

```
s3://path/to/bucket/hello/world.txt
```

The output I would like to have it returned is:

```
['s3://path/to/bucket/foo.txt', 's3://path/to/bucket/bar.txt', 's3:////path/to/bucket/baz.txt']
```

What am I missing in the regular expression?

Answer (score 2):

Try running this command :

```
s3cmd ls {s3bucket} --recursive | tr -s ' ' | cut -d " " -f 4
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's something I would do without regex:

```
def parse_dir (output):
    if output == "":
        return []
    else:
        dir_list = []
        line = output.split('\n')
        for var in line:
            if var != "":
                dir_list.append(var.split()[3])
        return dir_list[1:]
```

Comment: You still have to ignore the first element (which is just the directory itself: `'s3://dgsecure/test_data/'`)